# Error trying using recharts in typescript project

Tags: typescript, recharts, react-tsx

Hi i have installed recharts and @types/recharts in my project. Now when i try to import any chart to a component i have this error:

Failed to compile.

/Users/rmanreza/Projects/portfolio/node_modules/recharts/types/cartesian/YAxis.d.ts
TypeScript error in /Users/rmanreza/Projects/portfolio/node_modules/recharts/types/cartesian/YAxis.d.ts(1,13):
'=' expected.  TS1005

> 1 | import type { FunctionComponent, SVGProps } from 'react';
> |             ^
> 2 | import { BaseAxisProps, AxisInterval } from '../util/types';
> 3 | interface YAxisProps extends BaseAxisProps {
> 4 |     yAxisId?: string | number;

This is how package.json look like:

*

{   "name": "portfolio",   "version": "0.1.0",   "private": true,      "dependencies": {    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.30",    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",    "@types/recharts": "^1.8.19",    "axios": "^0.21.1",    "formik": "^2.2.6",    "react": "^16.13.1",    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",    "react-icons": "^3.11.0",    "react-router": "^5.2.0",    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",    "recharts": "^2.0.7",    "styled-components": "^5.1.1",    "typescript": "^3.7.5",    "yup": "^0.29.3"   },
....
*
I dont know how to fix that and so i can use recharts

Comment: It's not really a solution, so I'm not posting it as an "answer", but as a comment. I reverted back from 2.0.7 to 2.0.3 and I no longer have this issue.

Comment: @CherryNerd Thanks it worked.

Answer (score 5):

This is caused by `recharts` using TypeScript ^3.8. TypeScript 3.8 introduced a [new syntax to import and export types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html), which `recharts` has taken advantage of. `recharts` should have bumped the major version number because this is a breaking change (as you discovered). In order to use the latest version of `recharts`, you will need to bump your version of TypeScript to at least 3.8.